# Disable through the BIOS a faulty RAM module or make the BIOS emulate an Error Correction Code when the RAM itself has none?

Tags: memory, bios

A memtest revealed that I have a faulty RAM module on my motherboard. As on most computers, my RAM haven't Error Correction Codes (ECC) and it causes various troubles during working sessions.

Among the eight RAM modules I have, I can't say which stick exactly is the one involved, and the modules are behind an heavy heat sink for the CPU : I fear having not enough knowledge and tools to remove it and replace it after correctly.

I have not much hope, but... is there a way, through the BIOS :

1. To disable a single memory module ? Then I would perform a memtest on the remaining modules until I could isolate the faulty one ?
2. To emulate a correction code (at the cost the computer would become slower) ?

Comment: RAM doesn't need to be lifted much, so there might be enough room to lift RAM out. Have you tried lifting RAM out before on any computer? As long as you can slide two fingers a finger on each side of the RAM module, then you should be able to remove RAM without removing the heatsink from the CPU.

Comment: You don't need tools to put RAM in and out. Watch youtube videos of people replacing RAM, you'll see how easy it is and how you don't need much space to work with. Also, your computer isn't that well designed if it doesn't give you much room to work with to remove RAM, you should look up upgrading RAM and Hard Drive for a computer you are going to buy on youtube before you get the computer.

Comment: The heat-sink over the CPU is large and cover four of the eight RAM modules : it has to be removed before having an access to them. They cannot be lifted by hand before. I don't have the tools and the knowledge for removing the heat-sink over the CPU and I won't do it.

Comment: You could try removing the four that are accessible and see if that solves it.(If so, then  running it with one extra module each time to troubleshoot to see which of the 4 messes it up / which of the four is faulty).

Comment: It's not the subject of my post. I search a way to avoid removing them at the moment.

Comment: Windows or Linux.

Comment: @harrymc surely whether he is running windows or linux is so irrelevant, because when it comes to looking at RAM you can try booting off a USB and there are Win PE OSs and  Unix  based OSs that run off USB, aren't there. So why do you think it matters what he has on his hard drive? And if you can solve it either way, for windows or for linux, then posting both solutions is very good. And if you can only solve it for one OS then you could say so

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a method of blocking bad RAM in the BIOS.
Under Linux you can mark it using Grub and under Windows by `bcdedit`,
so that the boot might succeed.
If the bad memory still blocks the boot process in spite of this,
there is no solution except replacing it.

**Linux**

The method using Grub is by editing the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst`,
find a line that looks like:

```
kopt=root=UUID=f0906667-bcde-4b64-86bc-5a47320d5517 ro
```

and append to it the bad memory specification.
For example, for bad memory at 804M and 806M we would append the following text:
`memmap=10M$800M`.
Terminate by running `sudo update-grub`.

For more details see
[Bad Memory HowTo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140806175048/https://bryanquigley.com/planet-ubuntu/bad-memory-howto).

It's also possible to patch the kernel for that.
The details are found in the blog
[BadRAM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM).

**Windows**

The article
[Blacklist bad memory addresses in Windows](https://www.xf.is/blacklist-bad-memory-addresses-in-windows)
describes how to use `bcdedit` to mark bad memory, using the commands:

```
# Enable memory blacklisting
bcdedit /set {badmemory} badmemoryaccess no
# Specify what addresses to blacklist
bcdedit /set {badmemory} badmemorylist 0x1bfae5 0x116a3f
```

To verify, use:

```
bcdedit /enum {badmemory}
```

If you are using MemTest to find the bad addresses, note that it returns byte
addresses that need to be truncated to 4K blocks, by truncating the address.
The above command was for errors on 0x1BFAE5474 and 0x116A3FE55.

The `bcdedit` command suffers from lack of support for ranges, so every bad
block of 4KB must be specified on one line that is limited in size.
The Github project
[BadMemory](https://github.com/prsyahmi/BadMemory)
solves the problem using a driver created to overcome the issue.

(Note: No guarantee that the above will keep on working in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to see a motherboard on which either of the two things you are asking for is possible. You will need to test the modules one by one to identify which one is faulty and replace it.

Be prepared for the nasty situation where all modules check out just fine individually but not together, if the problem is caused by anything but outright failure. The vast majority of memory problems are due to modules being marginal rather than faulty. This is why ECC is indispensable for any serious application.